# Lightbox iFrame problem

Tags: jquery, iframe, lightbox

I have an iFrame that is loaded with a lightbox.  The problem I am having is this.  I want the parent page to redirect to a different page after a link in the lightbox pop up is clicked.  Does this make sense?  Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to define a javascript function in your parent frame to be called in your child frame.

eg in your parent frame if your using jQuery :

```
function redirectFromFrame(link){
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

and in your lighbox frame you should have something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(parent.redirectFromFrame($(this).attr('href')));
});
```

Comment: So on the code for the parent frame, where you have href = link; is where I add my link? and the code for the child frame, what do i put for the a and the href.  Sorry for the dumb questions.  Not that strong with javascript